# Stopping image responsiveness at a particular breakpoint Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my rails application, I have scaled my background image to be responsive using the style tag as you can see from the code below, and it works.

`<div><%= image_tag('slider4.jpg', style:'height:auto; width:100%;')%></div>`

> *But I want its responsiveness to stop at a particular breakpoint, lets say when the width is about 786px.*

Comment: Have you looked at the css style [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)?

Comment: Yes, but for some reason `max-width` does not work when I tried it. Here is what I used in that case `min-width: 100%; max-width: none;`

Comment: Why would you use `max-width:none`? If you want the maximum width of your image to be 768px then you would use that as your value: `max-width:768px`

Comment: okay, but when I used `<div><%= image_tag('slider4.jpg', style:'height:auto; max-width:786px;')%>`, it remains scaled to 786px and above that breakpoint, no responsiveness. All I want is just to stop it from being responsive at 786px downwards. above 786px it should be responsive.

Comment: Use it with `width`, `width:100%; max-width:768px;` that tells it to use 100% of the parent's width but not over 768px, if it doesn't work you might have other styles acting on it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I think you made a mistake. If we specify parent's width to 100%, we cant still specify `max-width` to a particular pixel as suggested. If we do that, `it will set max-width alone and will never scale beyond it`. I think it will be better to use `min-width` to achieve the title of the question posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments base, right on the question, the answer is deduced from it.

Using this code below, sets parent's width to 100% and also specifies minimum width not go beyond 768px.

```
<div><%= image_tag('slider4.jpg', style:'height:auto; width:100%; min-width: 768px;') %>
```

That surely works.